# PHP 7.1 PDO Postgres "could not find driver" exception on AWS EC2 Linux AMI

Tags: php, postgresql, amazon-web-services, pdo

Running PHP 7.1 on an AWS EC2 instance using the Amazon Linux AMI, my PHP application is giving the following exception while trying to connect to a PostgeSQL database with PDO:

`uncaught exception "could not find driver"`

Looking in `/etc/php.d/` it looks like no PostgreSQL driver is installed. How do I install the PHP 7.1 PDO driver for PostgreSQL on Amazon Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Amazon Linux for PHP 7.1, the command you're looking for is:

`sudo yum install php71-pgsql`

Yum should find a package named `php71-pgsql-7.1.33-1.43.amzn1.x86_64` from the `amzn-updates` repo.